# Lagrangian to Hamiltonian

Tags: differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation, physics, variational-calculus

I want to go from Lagrangian description to Hamiltonian one. Using [*the example given by Mathematica*](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4656/LagrangianEquations.nb?file_id=4146) I do something like:

```
genCoords = {x[t]};
T = 1/2 m x'[t]^2;
V = 1/2 K x[t]^2;
Q = -c x'[t];
L = T-V;
```

Now I want the Hamiltonian which is given by the relation :
$$p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}$$ and $$H=\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}-L$$

The result I want is `H` as a function of $q$ and $p$ and I don't understand how to calculate the set `{p[t]}` nor to replace it inside the expression of the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how you would do it using the standard add-on package [`VariationalMethods`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html), which is meant for calculations like this:

```
Clear[m, k, c, x, t];
T = 1/2 m x'[t]^2;
V = 1/2 k x[t]^2;
L = T - V;

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

hamiltonianEq = 
 h == FirstIntegral[t] /. Last[FirstIntegrals[L, {x[t]}, t]]

(* ==> h == 1/2 (k x[t]^2 + m Derivative[1][x][t]^2) *)

momentumEq = p[x] == VariationalD[L, x'[t], t]

(* ==> p[x] == m Derivative[1][x][t] *)

h /. 
 First[Solve[Eliminate[{hamiltonianEq, momentumEq}, x'[t]], h]]

(* ==> (p[x]^2 + k m x[t]^2)/(2 m) *)
```

Here, I defined two equations defining the Hamiltonian and momentum using the capabilities of the `VariationalMethods` package, and then used `Eliminate` to combine these equations into the final result.

The result is in simplified form, but you can also split it into two terms (which is more standard), by adding `Apart@` in front of it.

**For time-dependent Hamiltonians:**

The above works for Hamiltonians that are equal to the conserved energy, as is the case in the question. However, it's easy to modify the definition of `hamiltonianEq` above so that it also works in general, following the definition given in the question. You would replace the first equation by

```
hamiltonianEq = h == x'[t] VariationalD[L, x'[t], t] - L
```

The rest stays the same.

Answer (score 10):

```
genCoords = {x[t]};
ke = 1/2 m x'[t]^2;
v = 1/2 k x[t]^2;
q = -c x'[t];
l = ke - v;
```

Solve for `x'[t]` in terms of `p[t]`:

```
rule = First@Solve[p[t] == D[l, x'[t]], x'[t]]
(* {x'[t] -> p[t]/m} *)
```

and then replace this expression into the Hamiltonian:

```
x'[t] D[l, x'[t]] - l /. rule
(* p[t]^2/(2 m) + 1/2 k x[t]^2 *)
```

Note that I have used lower-case symbols for all of your variables. This is to avoid conflicts with built-in *Mathematica* symbols like `K`, which you used. This is good *Mathematica* practice.

Comment: This is the simplest answer, but it hasn't kept me from adding a more complicated alternative which may be of interest in more general situations. Especially for people who don't remember the definitions and don't want to look them up...

Comment: @Jens, ...of which there are a frightening lot. :o