# Finding Hamiltonian from a perturbative Action

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics, algebraic-manipulation, variational-calculus

I am given a perturbative action $$\frac{S}{\mathcal{T}}=\int dt\sum _{n=0,1} (\dot{c_n}{}^2-c_n^2 \omega _n^2)+7.11 c_0^3+35.3 c_0 c_1^2+4.66 c_0 \dot{c_0}{}^2+1.32 c_0 \dot{c_1}{}^2-7.57 \dot{c_0} c_1 \dot{c_1}$$ ($\omega _0^2=-1.4$ and $\omega _1^2=7.57$).

```
    \[Omega]sq[0] = -1.4; \[Omega]sq[1] = 7.57;
    lagrangian = 
      Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2 \[Omega]sq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
       7.11 c[0][t]^3 + 35.3 c[0][t] c[1][t]^2 + 
       4.66 c[0][t] c[0]'[t]^2 + 1.32 c[0][t] c[1]'[t]^2 - 
       7.57 c[0]'[t] c[1][t] c[1]'[t];
```

I tried finding the hamiltonian by hand and found out it to be equal to:

```
    H[t_] = c[0]'[t]^2 + c[1]'[t]^2 + 4.66 c[0][t] c[0]'[t]^2 + 
       1.32 c[0][t] c[1]'[t]^2 - 7.57 c[0]'[t] c[1][t] c[1]'[t] - 
       1.40 c[0][t]^2 + 7.57 c[1][t]^2 - 7.11 c[0][t]^3 - 
       35.3 c[0][t] c[1][t]^2;
```

How shall I use Mathematica to verify the above result?

Comment: **(1)** Is this a Mathematica question? **(2)** If so please include code and define all symbols **(3)** Do you seek to codify an existing algorithm or are you searching for a new algorithm? If so then can this question can be asked more suitably at the Math SE?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by easily. Isn't the Lagrangian the integrand of the action? Hence, a sum of derivatives w.r.t to the dotted coordinates of the iintegrand times themselves minus the integrand? @Syed the code is there. Is it possible you missed the edit?

Comment: @bmf yes basically I wish to find the hamiltonian from the lagrangian. Since I am working with a complicated problem where the numerical values keep changing, I am trying to find a suitable code to work around the problem, instead of doing it repetitively on a notebook. I have checked out this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113017/lagrangian-to-hamiltonian but don't understand how to implement it in my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure is basically what you would do by hand,
$
\mathcal{H} = \pi \dot{\phi} - \mathcal{L}
$
So just define the momentum $\pi$ as usual

```
momentum[n_] := D[lagrangian, c[n]'[t]]
```

and then

```
hamiltonian = Sum[momentum[n] c[n]'[t], {n, {0, 1}}] - lagrangian
```

gives the result you found by hand (if you `Expand`).  If you need a symbol with a passable `t`, you can add

```
h[t_] = hamiltonian
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! The results match perfectly :)